# Any way to get certificate of completion from DocuSign getAgreementPdf

Tags: node.js, rest, docusignapi, clickwrap

I am using DocuSign [clickWrap API](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/click-api/reference/accounts/clickwraps/) to download completed clickwraps;

I am able to download the completed clickwrap only - not able to find a way to download the completion certificate as part of the clickwrap response (like we have in the web UI)... there is no option in the [API document for getAgreementPdf](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/click-api/reference/accounts/clickwraps/getagreementpdf/) either

[image: certificate of completion option in the web UI]

Comment: @InbarGazit, can you help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the certificate through the [`getAgreementPdf` endpoint](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/click-api/reference/accounts/clickwraps/getagreementpdf/)
by appending the query parameter: `include_coc=true`. This seems to be missing from the live documentation, but is present in the [Swagger spec](https://www.docusign.net/clickapi/v1/schemas/swagger).

Full example:

```
GET /clickapi/v1/accounts/{accountId}/clickwraps/{clickwrapId}/agreements/{agreementId}?include_coc=true
```

The agreement ID can be found either through the callback of `onAgreed`:

```js
docuSignClick.Clickwrap.render({
   //...
   onAgreed: (agreementData) => {
     // agreementData.agreementId
   }
}, '#host-element');
```

Or through a POST to [`createHasAgreed`](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/click-api/reference/accounts/clickwraps/createhasagreed/) with the same `clientUserId`.

Comment: You rock @Stephen

Answer (score -1):

You can get the certificate of completion by calling this endpoint:

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/get/

"If the account option Attach certification of completion to envelope is on, then the Certificate of Completion is also included in the PDF file."

Comment: This endpoint is for eSign. Would it work for clickWraps also?