# DocuSign clickwraps are not working on developers.docusign.com

Tags: javascript, docusignapi, clickwrap

the test link generated on their site is also not working and resulting in the following - this is happening for all clickwraps (either through the test link or the embed code that is generated)

[image: DocuSign clickWrap loading issue]

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for notifying us of this issue. Our engineers are working to resolve the issue in the DEMO environment.

Comment: Hi @IvanD, any possibility to get certificate of completion for clickWrap? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67496770

Comment: UPDATE - Clicwrap is fixed in demo

Comment: @AkberIqbal do you still have a problem?

Comment: All good @InbarGazit on PROD version... gave up on the DEMO as it was affecting our timelines... but happy to see you guys so responsive here